# Translate string inside twig template

Tags: translation, plugin-wpml

I am trying to translate a string inside a placeholder in a twig (timber) template. But I cannot detect the string in WPML string translation.

```
<input type="text" id="s" name="s" value="" placeholder="{{ __('Search', 'textdomain') }}">
```

Comment: I'd guess WPML scans your code for potential translations and isn't picking this up then? Maybe try adding a reference to that translation somewhere in PHP code and see if that helps. And this is possibly a bug or enhancement report for WPML.

Comment: it is working fine with php code, just the strings inside twig template are not working

Answer (score 1):

I managed to assign a variable to context.

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['search_placeholder'] = __("Suche","pixel_framework");

Timber::fetch('test.twig',$context);
```

inside twig

```
<input type="text" id="s" name="s" value="" placeholder=" {{search_placeholder}}">
```

Comment: Interesting solution, because I think the issue is that the code in `.twig` files is not scanned by WPML, only in `.php` files. This seems sensible, potentially a locale file could even be created to store all of these and add them to context. e.g. `en.php`